# Boost Signed/Unsigned Comparsion of size_type and index of multi_array

Tags: c++, boost, multidimensional-array, integer, boost-multi-array

I'm using a `boost::multi_array` and when I need to check if a given coordinate is within bounds, I do this:

```
bool MapData::IsWithinBounds(TileArray3D::index x, TileArray3D::index y, TileArray3D::index z) const {
    return (x >= 0 and x < GetWidth()) and
           (y >= 0 and y < GetHeight()) and
           (z >= 0 and z < GetDepth());
}
```

where `TileArray3D` is defined as:

```
typedef boost::multi_array<TileID, 3> TileArray3D;
```

and `TileID` is:

```
BOOST_STRONG_TYPEDEF(int, TileID);
```

The signature of GetWidth/Height/depth is:

```
TileArray3D::size_type GetWidth() const;
```

But `TileArray3D::size_type` is unsigned and `TileArray3D::index` is signed. Am I using these types in the wrong way? Or is there a way around this? Should I just cast the `index`'s to `size_type`'s? or can problems occur?

Thanks in advance, ell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the size of `size_type` is at least as large as the size of `index`, just cast the indices to `size_type` for that comparison. Since you checked for non-negativity before, there can't be overflow then, so it's safe.